# Change delimiters in files

Tags: csv, sed, awk

Below I have files as they should, and further down, what I made till now. I think that in my code is the source of the problem: delimiters, but I can't get it much better.

My source file is with `;` as delimiter, and the files for my database have a `,` as separator; also, the strings are between "":

The category file should be like this:

```
"1","1","testcategory","testdescription"
```

And the manufacturers file, like this:

```
"24","ASUS",NULL,NULL,NULL
"23","ASROCK",NULL,NULL,NULL
"22","ARNOVA",NULL,NULL,NULL
```

What I have at this moment:

```
- category file:
1;2;Alarmen en beveiligingen;
2;2;Apparatuur en toebehoren;
3;2;AUDIO;

- manufacturers file:
315;XTREAMER;NULL;NULL;NULL
316;XTREMEMAC;NULL;NULL;NULL
317;Y-CAM;NULL;NULL;NULL
318;ZALMAN;NULL;NULL;NULL
```

I tried a bit around to use `sed`; first, on the categories file:

```
cut -d ";" -f1 /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv |sort | uniq >        /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.csv
sed 's/^/;2;/g' /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.csv > /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.tmp
sed -e "s/$/;/" /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.tmp > /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.tmp2
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}{printf("%s%s\n",n++,$0)}' /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description-in.tmp2 > /home/arno/pixtmp/categories_description$
```

And then on the manufacturers file:

```
cut -d ";" -f5 /home/arno/pixtmp/pixtmp.csv |sort | uniq > /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-in
sed 's/^/;/g' /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-in > /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-tmp
sed -e "s/$/;NULL;NULL;NULL/" /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-tmp > /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-tmp2
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}{printf("%s%s\n",n++,$0)}' /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers-tmp2 > /home/arno/pixtmp/manufacturers.ok
```

Comment: Your outputs and inputs do not seem to present the same content; please, change only the formatting, so that we may know what you're trying to do.

Comment: What happens if, in a string, there is a , or ; or " ? How do you desire the metacharacters to be escaped between formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to solve the problem by using cut, sed, and AWK.  AWK by itself is powerful enough to solve your problem.

I wrote one AWK program that can handle both of your examples.  If NULL is not a special case, and the manufacturers' file is a different format, you will need to make two AWK programs but I think it should be clear how to do it.

All we do here is tell AWK that the "field separator" is the semicolon.  Then AWK splits the input lines into fields for us.  We loop over the fields, printing as we go.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ";"

    DQUOTE = "\""
}

function add_quotes(s) {
    if (s == "NULL")
        return s
    else
        return DQUOTE s DQUOTE
}

NF > 0 {
    # if input ended with a semicolon, last field will be empty
    if ($NF == "")
        NF -= 1  # subtract one from NF to forget the last field

    if (NF > 0)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF - 1; ++i)
            printf("%s,", add_quotes($i))
        printf("%s\n", add_quotes($i))
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much..but it's not quite clear how to call this file..I mean, i put the code in a file, chmod +x and then call the file like ./fixfile or ./fixfile manufacturers ?

Comment: Yes, that will work.  You can also put it into a file (such as `extract3_5.awk`) and run it explicitly with AWK: `awk -f extract3_5.awk < input_file.txt > output_file.txt`

Comment: Thank you very much.. (i stopped programming when i was 10yr old..and that programming was gwbasic..now i'm slowly starting again.. so really many tnx for the help (all of you..))